# Elasticsearch docker container taking all my disk space, cannot find where

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

Here's my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro

      # data
      - ./data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - elk-network

  kibana:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk-network
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk-network:
    name: elk-network
    driver: bridge
```

I do docker-compose up, each day my drive space gets lower by 3-4gb. If I bash into the containers and look for biggest files, there are no big files. If I do container ls, the containers are only 2gb and don't grow in size.

But if I do docker-compose down, and up again, all my disk space is restored. What is going on? How do I debug what is taking all my space for apparently no reason?

if I look for biggest files on my host machine I believe it's all in the /var/lib/docker (or something similar I lost the exact location before clearing all the space).

Comment: looks like you are binding the host `.data` folder to your docker directory `./data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw`, all your data should be in `.data` and its not persistent, hence when you down your docker container that data is also lost.

Comment: I dont know what you're taking about. that's a bind mount and it is persistant. It's not affected by up/down and this folder only grows a few MB daily.

Comment: I do docker-compose up, each day my drive space gets lower by 3-4gb.?? this is from your post, its confusing is it getting lower or increased and also now you are saying its not affected by `up/down`?

Comment: my entire disk drive goes up 3-4gb per day, this specific folder is not affected. Most of the space growing comes from /var/lib/docker or something like that. the data folder is persistant and not affected.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. No trace of the files taking up extra room, and my host's /var/lib/docker/volumes/xxx for the container volume increases by 25 GB every day.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off swap in your host

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Comment: how would this help? Is docker running out of ram, using swap, and then not cleaning it? I thought that was handled by the OS

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, that'd be my guess. If your disk space gets restored as soon as you bring the containers down then it's a likely scenario